# Build error in Android Open Source Project

Tags: android, android-source

I am new to AOSP and trying to build the code in my ubuntu machine. I have made slight changes in a class in the Framework. Now trying to run the build the code. I have followed the commands in [this link](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building) and finding errors in the terminal. the error is given in the bellow:

```html
error: packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/Android.bp:20:1: "framework-tethering.stubs.source" depends on undefined module "framework-
connectivity"
error: packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/Android.bp:20:1: "framework-tethering.stubs.source.system" depends on undefined module "fra
mework-connectivity"
error: packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/Android.bp:20:1: "framework-tethering.stubs.system" depends on undefined module "framework-
connectivity"
error: packages/modules/Wifi/framework/Android.bp:115:1: "framework-wifi.stubs.module_lib" depends on undefined module "framework-connectivity"
error: packages/modules/Wifi/framework/Android.bp:115:1: "framework-wifi.stubs" depends on undefined module "framework-connectivity"
error: packages/modules/Wifi/framework/Android.bp:115:1: "framework-wifi.stubs.system" depends on undefined module "framework-connectivity"
error: packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/Android.bp:20:1: "framework-tethering.stubs" depends on undefined module "framework-connect
ivity"
error: packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/Android.bp:20:1: "framework-tethering.impl" depends on undefined module "framework-connecti
vity"
error: packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/Android.bp:20:1: "framework-tethering.stubs.module_lib" depends on undefined module "framew
ork-connectivity"
error: packages/modules/IPsec/Android.bp:19:1: "android.net.ipsec.ike.stubs" depends on undefined module "framework-connectivity"
error: packages/modules/IPsec/Android.bp:19:1: "android.net.ipsec.ike.stubs.system" depends on undefined module "framework-connectivity"
error: packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/Android.bp:20:1: "framework-tethering.stubs.source.module_lib" depends on undefined module 
"framework-connectivity"
error: packages/modules/IPsec/Android.bp:19:1: "android.net.ipsec.ike.stubs.module_lib" depends on undefined module "framework-connectivity"
18:29:20 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

Thank you in advance for guiding me in the next process. At the same time, what would be the best online sources for having a more in-depth tutorial on developing in AOSP

Comment: Are you executing the build command from the root of the source tree? This error seems to be due to being in some nested framework folder that is unable to find a dependent module definition.

Comment: `m framework` should help.